# Dojo multistate checkbox trees in 1.5+

Tags: dojo

trying to convert a 1.3 app to 1.5+
It has a multistate check box tree object.  Hierarchy of checkboxes and you can check all child check boxes by checking the parent.

I can only find 1.4 and earlier examples of checkbox trees

can someone point me at a 1.5 version or suggestions on what to do to convert from 1.3 to 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this one. Works for me even in Dojo 1.6

http://www.thejekels.com/dojo/Dijit_Tree_MultiState_Chkbox.html

Comment: sorry it took me so long to respond.  Yes it works making use of it in my app is problematic,  for some reason I cannot parent checkbox to check all the children recursively..